# How to break a loop in bs4

Tags: python, breakpoints, extract

I am trying to extract some info using beautiful soup. I want to extract some infor that are located in the top of the html and once it finds a unique attribute to break or stop looking and continue to the next iteration.

This is the code I have about the info I want to extract.

```
for mainbody in soup2.find_all('div',class_="thread_body"):
    main_body.append([mainbody.get_text().strip()])
```

This I want to be the point where it should stop looking in the html source.

```
<span class="replies">15</span>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `if` statement in your script and use `break`. `break` will stop the innermost looping that is running. I don't know what you really want to do, so I suggesting something that may work in your case:

```
for mainbody in soup2.find_all('div',class_="thread_body"):
    a = mainbody.get_text().strip()
    if a == '15':
        main_body.append(a)
        # get out from this for loop
        break
```